# How to parse my JSON String in Android?

Tags: android, json, parsing

[{"id":"1","name":"Nurullah","surname":"xxxxxx","il":"eskisehir"},{"id":"2","name":"Ozgur","surname":"yyyyyy","il":"istanbul"},{"id":"3","name":"Emre","surname":"zzzzzz","il":"ankara"}]

I showed my JSON above. I dont know that how can i parse my string in android? thank yo for answers.

Comment: Please Google first before posting question here.

Comment: What have you done till now?

Comment: @Denny Don't use this post as a reference please. There are historical reasons it still exists, otherwise it wouldn't be there anymore.

Comment: i looked for it in google, but i dont understand for their json format that is different. @chintan-soni

Comment: @greenhoorn I think you're misinterpreting the banner note, there. Though we no longer want questions asking for step-by-step instructions, guides, or tutorials, the information in the answers there is still perfectly valid, and can be used for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically **'[]' this represent as JSONArray** and **'{}' this represent JSONObject**

```
 try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
            String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
            String surname = jsonObject.getString("surname");
            String il = jsonObject.getString("il");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: to know more about JSON follow this http://www.elated.com/articles/json-basics/

Comment: If you help with my answer pls vote up.. thanks